# Visualization of large combination of groups using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, holoviews

I have a data frame with a structure similar to

```
dt, ing_net, egs_net, ing_ip, egs_ip, avg_pkt, sum_time
2017-01-01, A2, A1, 10.100.0.0, 22.54.23.0, 12.1, 123
2017-01-01, B2, A1, 10.100.1.0, 22.54.23.0, 12.1, 982
2017-01-01, B2, A2, 10.0.1.0, 22.54.13.0, 92.1, 692
...
2017-06-31, A2, B8, 65.200.0.0, 33.0.23.0, 12.7, 99887
```

and the possible number of combinations between `ing_net` and `egs_net` is 250. How can I visualize one of the value variables, say `avg_pkt`, for all possible combinations? I'm looking for a visual aid or approach to search for outliers.

Seaborn `FacetGrid` cannot plot all graphs:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='egs_net', column='ing_net', 'avg_pkt')
g.map(sns.distplot)
# all plots are extremely small and with wrong x datetime axis
```

Doing a groupby on the pandas dataframe generates all graphs, but not in a grid:

```
for name, group in df_avg.groupby(['egs_net', 'ing_net']):
  group.plot(x='dt', y='avg_pkt', title='{} - {}'.format(name[0], name[1]), figsize=(7,5), subplots=True)
```

and a Holoviews HoloMap bails with the number of intermediate graphs:

```
hv_df = hv.Dataset(df.reset_index(), kdims=['dt', 'egs_net', 'ing_net'])
hv_df.to(hv.Curve, vdims=['avg_pkt'])
```

How can I explore this phase space?

Comment: Usually you would first think about how to visualize some data and then select the right tool to do it. So if you can tell how the graph should look like, I guess one can help achieving that goal. But without any clue about what you want to represent, I fear this question is hard to answer.

Comment: I'm looking for outliers and need to compare the behavior by the group level.

Comment: Have you tried a gridmatrix of hv.Bivariate?
 (http://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/iris_density_grid.html)?  Probably too much data to work with at once, I suppose. In any case, if you ever have a problem with HoloMap having too much data, just use a DynamicMap to render the data on the fly.